# What is this array ternary like in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am reviewing some code in php that use zend framework in some statements they use something like: 
    `$where['uniqueid = ?'] = $songid;`
what means that `'foo = ?'` key in the array.
sorry if i wasn't very specific because don't know how to call that statement and i didn't found something about it.

Comment: Where are you using the ternary operator? The code you provided makes an index in the $where array with the value 'uniqueid = ?'. It isn't doing anything other than assigning the value given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is `'uniqueid = ?'`

This is not the ternary operator. It is the key of the [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). While it is uncommon for them to have spaces, PHP nonetheless allows keys to be integers or strings.

I would guess this convention is being used to bind query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Jason's assumption is correrct. This is a way of binding query string parameters with Zend DB. See documentation: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.6/Zend_Db/Select/Zend_Db_Select.html#methodwhere